auto py to exe output incomplete operation due to file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software
I'm currently converting multiple .py program into one directory exe file using Auto Py to Exe yet the operation keeps on being incomplete due to

error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (225, 'BeginUpdateResourceW',
'Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a
virus or potentially unwanted software.')

I tried shutting down the computer firewall and antivirus, but I still do get the same response'Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software.'
